# How to list by the according data when I choose data to nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When i create a new record and select plateNo from option menu in addRecord I just want it to be listed by the license plate I chose in index page. Any advice?

addRecord.handlebars

```
        <form action="/records/save" method="POST">
                ....
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="plateNo">
                        {{#each vehicles}}
                        <option value="{{id}}">{{plate}}</option>
                        {{/each}}
                    </select>
                </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-danger login_btn">
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

//Router records.js

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
Record.create({
    ...req.body,
    driver: req.session.userId
})
res.redirect('/')
```

})

//Model Record.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const RecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    initialTime: { type: String, required:true },
    initialKm: { type: String, required:true },
    from: { type: String, required:true },
    destination: { type: String, required:true },
    arrivalTime: { type: String, required:true },
    arrivalKm: { type: String, required:true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    plateNo: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'vehicles'},
    driver: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users'},
    city: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'cities'}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Record', RecordSchema)
```

[image]
[image]

[GitHub link](https://github.com/R8P/takip.git)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Perhaps you can show a screen where you show what you got, and marking what it *should* be?

Comment: I added screenshots. First one is records/new - for adding a new record. Second one is index page. All records are listing by this page.  I just want it to be listed by the license plate I chose in index page. For example 06ASD06.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you just need a help with how to write an API that calls Mongoose to filter some records? Or do you have NO IDEA what to do next?